# How to skip Microsoft Authentication?

Tags: typescript, authentication, playwright, playwright-typescript

I have my global setup file here:

```
// global-setup.ts
import { chromium, expect, FullConfig } from '@playwright/test';
import { loginPO } from './PageObjects/login.pageObject';

async function globalSetup(config: FullConfig) {
  const { baseURL } = config.projects[0].use;
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const login = new loginPO(page);
  await page.goto(baseURL!);
  require('dotenv').config();
  await login.signIn.click();
  await expect(login.usernameInput).toBeVisible();
  await login.usernameInput.pressSequentially(process.env.uname, {delay:100});
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
  await expect(page.locator('id=displayName')).toBeVisible();
  await login.passwordInput.pressSequentially(process.env.pword, {delay:100});
  await page.keyboard.press('Enter');
  await expect(login.stayLoggedInText).toBeVisible();
  await expect(login.passwordInput).toBeHidden();
  await login.continueButton.click();
  await expect(page.locator('//p[contains(text(), "View your data from Microsoft Graph")]')).toBeVisible({timeout:10000});
  await page.context().storageState({ path: 'userLogin.json' });
  await browser.close();
}
export default globalSetup;
```

Once the global set up is ran, I see the login file get created, and I confirmed that I am actually able to login during global setup when debug is ran, I have the storagestate stored here in my config file:

```
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';
require('./playwright.config');
require('dotenv').config();
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  globalSetup: require.resolve('./global-setup'),
  workers: 1,
  retries: 1,
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Backstage',
      use: {
        baseURL: process.env.URL,
        screenshot: "only-on-failure",
        video: "retain-on-failure",
        headless: true,
        storageState: 'userLogin.json', 
        viewport: { width: 1536, height: 850 },
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      } 
    }
  ]
};
export default config;
```

But when the tests run, I get faced with the login screen. Is there something extra that I need to do when dealing with microsoft authentication?

Here is my spec file:

```
import { expect, test } from '@playwright/test';
import { mainToolActions } from '../Actions/mainTool.actions';


test.describe('Navigate to different domains', () => {
  let mainTool;

  test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
    mainTool = new mainToolActions(page);
    test.setTimeout(10000);
    page.goto('/', {timeout:10000});
    return test.setTimeout(10000);
  });

  test('Click on Main tool', async () => {
    await mainTool.clickMainOption();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please share your `playwright.config` file

Comment: the config file is already in the post. But I figured out the issue, the assertion after global setup login needed to be changed because the script was ending before the login details were actually saved properly in the created json file.

Comment: All promises returned by Playwright must be awaited: `page.goto('/', {timeout:10000});` should be `await page.goto('/', {timeout:10000});`.